# how to dump the heap total new in node 16

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, heap-memory

Today I monitor the node(version 16) application and found the heap total new momory takes 100MB+ memory, my application is very small and simple. I have read the source code and did not found where will take 100Mb+ memory, is it possible to show the heap new memory size for each parts? what should I do to find out where takes these size? I have tried to use prometheus to monitor the heap size, but the prometheus only show the size, no more information, this is the prometheus UI:

[image]